# What is the correct order for the buttons on this window (for Windows operating system standards)?

Tags: windows, mfc, dialog

I am aware that there are standards for placement of buttons and I usually follow this order:

- OK | Do It | Yes
- Don't Do It | No
- Cancel
- Apply
- Help

However I have a couple of windows with different buttons:

[image: Window 1 Buttons]

Clearly some of these buttons need to be resorted as:

- OK
- Cancel
- Help

But where should **Print** and **Undo** fall in this row?

[image: Window 2 Buttons]

Should the **Order** button be **before** the **OK** button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positioning of the OK button was answered [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/1082) already, but if I understood correctly, your convention is placing it on the left, so you should keep it to that.

Regarding the other buttons, the OK button should certainly **not** be **between** any buttons. It should either be first or last, depending on your convention. In this case, OK should be first and Cancel second, while the rest is completely up to you.